# dompdf Page break if element is exceeding page height?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

What is the best way to do page breaks in dompdf?

I have had a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp) at the page-break-before css attribute, but it didn't work when I did:

```
table {page-break-before:auto;}
```

The page still breaks in the middle of my table.

Is it possible to setup my html/css so that the page will break before the element if the element is going to exceed the page height?

Ideally I would like to divide my html up in to div sections so that each section will start on a new page if it is going to exceed the height of the current page.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Using `page-break-inside: auto;` basically says to dompdf "do what you would normally do when breaking pages."

To force a page break before / after your table you would use `page-break-before: always;` / `page-break-after: always;`.

To ask dompdf to avoid breaking inside an element you would use `page-break-inside: avoid;`.

Comment: `page-break-inside:avoid;` made disappear images in table and has an issue especiall when using `colspan=2` in my case

Comment: Just a heads-up: I tried using the `page-break-inside: avoid` on `<tbody/>` and `<table/>` tags, as well as using `page-break-after: avoid` on a `<tr/>` – both gave me some extra empty pages. My solution was to wrap the tables in a `<div/>` with `page-break-inside: avoid` applied.

Comment: note this was not working with rowspan in tds, I finally switched to mpdf because it was a very simple (but long) table

Comment: `page-break-inside: auto;` doesn't work with elements larger than the pages UNFORTUNATELY...see: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/653 and https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/809

Comment: This is still a valid fix. I was unable to get my large table converted to PDF without cutting off content past the first page. The css rule page-break-after: always; Saved my but. I just add that rule inline every time the content gets close to the page height. Big thanks for this little trick!

Answer (score 11):

You might make quick tests with [this online debugger](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php) - i finally found my pagebreak and margin issue after days of testing.

Excursus: Did anyone install a debug environment on the development/production environment and can point me to any documentation or tutorial?

Comment: Makes sense checking the possible issues on this debugger. For example, a small change in CSS can affect big. Especially, the **dompdflog** tab is very handy.

Comment: Thanks for that debugger link, it's *very* useful.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a trick: place the `<table>` you do NOT want to print across multiple pages in another `<table>`.

Comment: or place it into <div>

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was happened since I have used a table inside another table.
Like,

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table></table>
      </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

So I did was getting the table out. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

//Firstly assign a variable before starting for loop and set post-increment operator inside for loop. secondly, use   with condition of data display item in a single page.

```
  <?php $n=1 ?>
          @foreach ($purchases as $key=> $purchase)
               <tr >
                   <td> {{ $key + 1 }}  </td>
                   <td> {{ $purchase->supplier->company_name ? 
                   $purchase->supplier->company_name : "" }}  </td>
                   <td> {{ "S-".$purchase->id  }}   </td>
                   <td> {{  salte_items($purchase->purchaseItems) }}        </td>
                   <td> {{ $purchase->created_at->format('d-m-Y') }}  </td>
                   <td> {{ intval($purchase->total) }}    </td>
                    </tr>
                  
                    @if ( $n % 25 == 0 )
                        <div style="page-break-before:always;"> </div>
                    @endif
                    <?php $n++ ?>

           @endforeach
```

Comment: Please add comments and explain your code

Comment: you can add your comment to your code by editing your answer

Comment: @phoenixstudio once the loop reach line 25  will force page-break